# Parse with swift for IOS application

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am a beginner to IOS applicaiton development as well as swift.I use Parse services for my application.
I have imported

```
Parse.framework,
ParseUI.framework,Social.framework,
Accounts.framework,
SystemConfiguration.framework,
Storekit.framework,
Security.framework,
QuartzCore.framework,
CoreLocation.framework,
CoreGraphics.framework,
CFNetwork.framework,
AudioToolbox.framework,
libsqllite3.dylib,
libz.dylib.
```

I have also imported UIKit,Parse and Bolts to all of my .swift files
But in any case,it shows use of unresolved identifier to Parse Objects when I use any Parse object.Why?Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out steps 2 and 3 here:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

You might not have "Copy items to destination's group folder" checked.

Also, cocoapods is a great way to manage libraries. Check out this tutorial if you're interested:
http://shrikar.com/integrate-parse-with-swift-in-ios8-using-cocoapods/